# How to make android app available on chromebook (react-native)

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, chromebook

I have a react-native android app in the play store.  It works on tablet and phone but for some reason it seems unavailable on chromebook.  When I go into my playstore account and have a look at supported devices the chromebook is there.  I have deleted the play store storage and cache and restarted the device and still the app isnt there.  When I link into the app it says that the app is not supported on the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you'll have to add [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/arc#update_your_apps_manifest_file) to your manifest to make sure your android app works on all chromebooks:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          ... >
    <!-- Some Chromebooks don't support touch. Although not essential,
         it's a good idea to explicitly include this declaration. -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
                  android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: this could very likely be the answer, im a bit derailed right now so cant test it out just yet but ill be sure to mark it correct when i get to fixing this in a week or two if it works

Comment: thanks and apologies this took me so long, finally got round to trying it and it worked!! so appreciated :)

Comment: No worries, I'm glad that helped!